# ERROR terasort.TeraSort: Input path does not exist: maprfs:/user/user01/–DXmx1024m

Tags: hadoop, mapr

While Running the `terasort` application by modifying the parameters I'm getting the following Error.

> 15/05/24 21:41:42 ERROR terasort.TeraSort: Input path does not exist: maprfs:/user/user01/–DXmx1024m

Command I'm running for executing the jog

```
$ hadoop jar /opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/hadoop-0.20.2-dev-\
examples.jar terasort –DXmx1024m –Dmapred.reduce.tasks=2 \
-Dio.sort.mb=1 /user/user01/6/TERA_IN /user/user01/6/TERA_OUT_2
```

If I remove these Parameters `–DXmx1024m –Dmapred.reduce.tasks=2 -Dio.sort.mb=1` then everything is working fine.

I think i'm facing the  below bug which is posted on jira but its for windows https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-8536

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a copy/paste issue from the MapR LAB GUIDE.

Just change '–' to '-' from the VM input parameters.

See the execution with copy/paste:

```
-bash-4.1$ hadoop jar /opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/hadoop-0.20.2-dev-\
> examples.jar terasort –DXmx1024m –Dmapred.reduce.tasks=2 \
> -Dio.sort.mb=1 /user/user01/6/TERA_IN /user/user01/6/TERA_OUT_2
15/10/26 15:24:57 INFO terasort.TeraSort: starting
15/10/26 15:24:59 ERROR terasort.TeraSort: Input path does not exist: maprfs:/user/user01/–DXmx1024m
-bash-4.1$
```

See the execution with the command line fixed:

```
-bash-4.1$ hadoop jar /opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/hadoop-0.20.2-dev-examples.jar terasort -DXmx1024m -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=2 -Dio.sort.mb=1 /user/user01/6/TERA_IN /user/user01/6/TERA_OUT_2
15/10/26 15:25:26 INFO terasort.TeraSort: starting
15/10/26 15:25:27 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you run teragen before you run terasort?

And what filesystem do you used? Why "maprfs". If it isn't on purpose, check your config files

```
15/05/24 21:41:42 ERROR terasort.TeraSort: Input path does not exist: **maprfs**:/user/user01/–DXmx1024m
```

Comment: I'm Using Mapr Distribution thats why its using maprfs, and I have executed teragen before executing terasort. and as i mention in my question If i remove the parameters then everything is executing fine.

Comment: "io.sort.mb" is used to  set the map output buffer, default is 100M. But you set it 1M, it's to small. Try to remove this parameter.